# Is there a way to peek into a stream and check whether it is not empty WITHOUT consuming the stream

Tags: java-8, stream

I wrote a piece of code which retrieves thousands of String objects from a rest endpoint in form of stream.

My issue is that the endpoint sends data in pages. Every page would have say 1000 elements. Now I don't know the number of pages beforehand.

So I have to get the page as stream -> look into it and check whether it is empty -> if not consume it. Else stop receiving more pages and move on to next `source`.

I tried `findFirst`, `findAny` ... you name it. All these are consumers and hence I cannot just check if the stream is empty or not with these as using these would effectively consume the stream.

I don't want to send request twice either -> one to check whether stream has elements. Then again send same request and retrieve the stream. That would double the download size.

**I came up with an idiotic solution by using `peek()`, with `AtomicBoolean`. Is there a way to better do this?**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicBoolean found = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    for (String source : sources) {
        // incoming requests are retrieved page by page
        int page = 0;
        do {
            page++;
            found.set(false);
            try (
                    Stream<String> stringStream = consumer
                            // get the feed
                            .connectToEndpoint(page, source)

                            // I don't know whether the page would be empty or not when retrieving
                            // So I peek into the stream and make sure there are elements inside
                            // So when this stream ends, I don't have to go for the next page

                            // ===================================================================
                            // The problem I face is that I have to peek every incoming object
                            // There is NOT a way to just look into the stream -> Oh its not empty -> Stop receiving more pages
                            // Even more problematic is the AtomicInteger
                            // Since it is slow, IMAGINE setting it to true at every incoming object
                            // ===================================================================
                            .peek(string -> found.set(true));

                    // I convert the string stream to some object stream and filter it out
                    // do further processing
            ) {
                // Then I take the stream, build a json request and write it to file

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // usually a server error -> see #connectToFeedEndpoint
                e.printStackTrace();
                page--;

                // give some time for server to relax
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            }

            System.out.printf("Source = %s, Page = %d, Found = %s \n", source, page, found.get());

            // This is where I check found
            // First page is likely to have elements -> So I'm using a do...while
            // At the end of first cycle I check whether found is true -> if it is then I loop again
        } while (found.get());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Streams are no-op until you ask for terminal operation that "consume" it. Once consumed, you can not play with it, no more.

Java 8 api says and greater version does not change anything on this point (emphasise is mine):

> To perform a computation, stream operations are composed into a stream
> pipeline. A stream pipeline consists of a source (which might be an
> array, a collection, a generator function, an I/O channel, etc), zero
> or more intermediate operations (which transform a stream into another
> stream, such as filter(Predicate)), **and a terminal operation** (which
> produces a result or side-effect, such as count() or
> forEach(Consumer)). **Streams are lazy; computation on the source data
> is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, and source
> elements are consumed only as needed**.

Comment: So is there a way to achieve what I intend to achieve with less overhead? peek() is unnecessary as it scans all elements and its atomic boolean so there is that overhead as well.